# any way to get back local history after `git git filter-repo -> git pull --allow-unrelated-histories`?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I may have discovered a great way to irrevocably delete valuable stuff.
Is there any way I can undo steps 1-2?

##### Background

1. I had a large file in a commit that caused a push error, so I tried to delete it with:

```
git filter-repo --path <this big file>--invert-paths --force
```

2. I tried to re-push the commit but git refused to do such without a pull from remote, which I did by:

```
git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories
```

3. Now several files open in my editor are marked as missing, and many more are gone or overwritten in the file system.  Here is the output of `git reflog`

```
$ git reflog --all 
01eb3b2 (origin/main) refs/remotes/origin/main@{0}: fetch origin: storing head
5ba15dd (HEAD -> main) refs/heads/main@{0}: commit (initial): update before s6, working on laplace alpha coeff
5ba15dd (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{0}: commit (initial): update before s6, working on laplace alpha coeff
```

4. For files that were not deleted by (1,2) above, I can actually see the history of uncommitted changes in Visual Studio Code using `<changed file> (Explorer View)->Open Timeline`.
   [image]
   However, I cannot do this with the many new local files that were apparently deleted when the remote was pulled in (2).  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: it looks like all the files you are concerned about were *committed* at some point, is that correct ? if it is : git has a big undo stack called the reflog : check `git reflog`, you should see the hash of the commit before you ran `git filter-repo` or `git pull`. If you don't care for your current (broken ?) modifications at all, you can return to that commit using `git reset --hard <that sha>`

Comment: Ok so regarding the output of `git reflog` below, would `5ba15dd` be the state before I ran  `git filter-repo --force`?:
`5ba15dd (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{0}: commit (initial): update before s6, working on laplace alpha coeff`

Comment: aka, how do I differentiate between the state before `git filter-repo` VS the state *after* `git filter-repo` but *before* `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories`?

Comment: If you don't understand how to read the reflog, post it.

Comment: @matt, sorry I've added the output to bullet (3) in the OP

Comment: Can you show more than that? I could be wrong but I find it unlikely that you've gone back far enough. Unless there is just one commit in this whole repo, or something.

Comment: I used a github 'Public Template' where the green "Code" button is replaced by "Use This Template".  Clicking that appears to squash the commit history and create a new private repo.  In my case, I had a few weeks worth of work on that template code (a package I'm writing) and it lives as a submodule inside a directory with all the data and extra stuff for my project.  This morning, I realized that the submodule code wasn't getting committed when pushing to my project repo, so I tried to commit it (shown in OP).  The output of `git reflog --all` really is everything that I can see

Comment: The reason `git filter-repo` demands to be run on a fresh clone, and thus makes a *new* repository that is *unrelated to the original repository* (and therefore should be sent to a *new* repository on a site like GitHub if you're using a site like GitHub), is precisely because this kind of filtering destroys the original repository. There's not a lot you can do if you've removed the originals.

Comment: In this particular case, though, you've *combined* the two unrelated repositories into a single repository. This gets messy, but it is possible to recover. The problem you'll have is dis-entangling the originals. I'm not sure what you did on GitHub afterward, but hopefully `git log --all --graph` will turn up both the original repository commits and the new ones.

Comment: The other remaining question, of course, is whether you committed and pushed the files that you no longer have. (More precisely, whether you made commits, and then pushed those commits, so that there are such commits in the new rejoined history.)

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @torek in the comments, my usage of git above destroyed the newly-created files whose only history was overwritten in the local repo.

***Therefore, the sequence of git commands described in the OP are irreversible.***

However, the fail-safe noted below may represent the only lifeline for the huge number of users connecting to remote environments in Visual Studio Code, who realize too late the consequences of abusing basic git commands.

##### Fail-safe for VSCode (>= 1.66) Remote Environments:

So it turns out that even though I was developing inside a remote dev container, [Visual Studio Code locally caches remote workspace changes since v.1.66](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_66#_local-history).  All I had to do was `Local History: Find Entry to Restore` to locate the change history for files which were deleted on remote file system by the `git filter-repo` command in the OP.

Comment: This `Local History: Find Entry to Restore` VSCode feature saved my day