# What benefit does VS Code's Timeline have when I commit my changes often?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

The [timeline view](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_44#_timeline-view) in Visual Studio Code shows Git commits interleaved with me manually saving the file while developing.

When I check the timeline view I see many "File Saved" checkpoints between each Git commit:

[image: timeline]

So I am really not sure about the usage of it, especially I run `git commit` quite frequently.

What benefits come from the timeline, given I commit my changes often?

Comment: What do you mean by "more granularity"?

Comment: @evolutionxbox you were right. Those words was confusing, so I changed it to more file saved time.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73886213/any-way-to-get-back-local-history-after-git-git-filter-repo-git-pull-allow

Comment: @matt thanks for the link. That seems to a way to use timeline info. But I doubt that is the reason vscode add timeline a major feature in their release note. To put it another way, I just don't see the value of timeline.

Comment: @evolutionxbox please see the comment below about the "granularity". That was what I meant.

Comment: (This comment is a bit borderline and I suspect it might get deleted, but:) Microsoft have a tradition of doing embrace-and-extend as an attempt to lock users into Microsoft. That is, they take something standard or open-source and add a feature they think users will find invaluable. If users *do* find it invaluable, users are now locked into the Microsoft ecosystem. If you personally don't find a feature particularly valuable, that's not their problem; they only have a problem if hardly anyone finds it valuable. Any time you find yourself wondering: "why did they do that?" this might be why.

Comment: Note that while the above might be considered somewhat rant-y, it's actually how things are supposed to work: if Microsoft really *do* come up with something that a lot of users value, that's good, isn't it? Even if it locks them in to Microsoft products, perhaps.

Comment: @torek I raised an issue to vscode https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/5664 Hope they can response.

Answer (score 2):

The timeline shows "everything" that happened to a file, Git commits are just one aspect of that.

"Everything" being file saves, Git commits and more that VS Code records and saves in its metadata cache for that file.

As you can see in the [changelog you link to](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_44#_timeline-view):

> [The Timeline] is a unified view for visualizing time-series events (for example, Git commits, file saves, test runs, etc.) for a file.
>
> [...]
>
> In this release, the built-in Git extension **contributes a timeline source** that provides the Git commit history of the specified file.

So the Git extension adds timeline entries, in addition to all other timeline sources (such as file operations).

If you never have had to recover a file from a local history backed up by your editor, you're using Git right (at least in that sense) and/or aren't using a Git UI that randomly throws away changes (looking at you, Git Kraken), so well done.

If a feature doesn't match *your* workflow, that doesn't mean it's not useful for other users. :)

Comment: Well I have to say I deliberately asked the question that way because I fear my question would just be closed as opinion based.

Comment: "what use does the timeline have"; "what the value does timeline add to git commit when I commit quite often"

Comment: Local history (which is what other IDEs call this feature) is very useful if you want to check what exactly you changed while experimenting when you didn't commit. If you really commit very frequently, then that granularity might not add so much for you, but for those who don't (many people will only commit when they are "done" by some metric, whether or not that's good is opinion-based) the added granularity can be very useful. So it might not be for you. That's fine. Not every feature is for everyone.

Comment: Or **tl;dr** when you commit often, then maybe it doesn't add much value. But not everyone does.

Comment: @Qiulang alright, let me edit your question into something readable that actually represents your question without being opinion-based.

Comment: @Qiulang I've updated your question and my answer accordingly. :)

Comment: Yes I have read both of them. Thanks and I have to say "What benefit does VS Code's Timeline have" is still quite opinion based. lol

Comment: @Qiulang in my opinion it's pretty objective.

Comment: I never see "test runs" on timeline. Have you ever seen that ? I think you can add that in my question and your answer if you see them.